# Stack pointer SP and activation record

Tags: memory-management

Stack is divided in activation records. We have stack pointer (SP) that points at the top of the stack, and Frame Pointer (FP) that points at the current activation record.

Does every activation record/stack frame have their own SP and FP?

Answer (score 1):

No. In most systems the previous FP value is pushed on the stack as part of the next activation record.